# What code optimization could be performed by a code generator at the following case?

Tags: optimization, if-statement, computer-science

Well,while reading a book,i found this -interesting i think- problem

**What code optimization** could be **performed**
by a code generator when building the
machine code representing the statement: **?**

**if** (X = 5) **then** (Z ← X + 2)

**else** (Z ← X + 4)

**EDIT:** As long as we know that X=5 we do not need to load X from memory registars every time to just make z=7. So if X=5 we only have to do assign 7 to Z without including X for the add

Comment: Assuming `=` is referring to a comparison, you never need to do `X + 2`, since you know `X` is always 5, therefore you just assign 7 directly.

Comment: so when you know that x=5 you dont need to load X every time from the memory. got it. thanks @EvanTrimboli

Comment: "*memory*" and "*registers*" are two different things.  Generally, you load from memory into registers, and store from registers to memory.

Comment: @RBarryYoung aah yeah,excuse me. Just some inconvenience with english